# Валидация числа с дробью или без?

Tags: php, kohana, валидация

Стандартно в `kohana` можно сделать валидацию на то содержится ли в массиве:

```
Valid::digit
Valid::numeric
Valid::decimal
```

А как быть в том случае если пользователь одновременно может отправить и целое, и в тоже время десятичное число? Как быть в таком случае, по моему стандартные правила валидации фреймворка к этому не располагают, разве что регулярками, но все же?

Comment: надо будет это на будущее разработчикам `kohana` оставить.

Comment: @Maris: я сам не пробовал, но неужели `Valid::decimal` не пропустит просто целое?

Comment: @VladD неа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И чем не устраивает [Valid::numeric()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Valid#numeric)?

Пропускает числа, в том числе отрицательные и десятичные.

```
var_dump(Valid::numeric('123.65')); // true
var_dump(Valid::numeric('123')); // true

echo '<hr />';

var_dump(Valid::digit('123.65')); // false
var_dump(Valid::digit('123')); // true

echo '<hr />';

var_dump(Valid::decimal('123.65')); // true
var_dump(Valid::decimal('123')); // false
```

Comment: а у меня парадокс, когда запятую ставишь вместо точки в десятичных, тогда пропускает, когда точка, то бракует.

Comment: @Maris: а посмотрите на локаль, небось русская стоит? В русской десятичный разделитель таки запятая.

Comment: ``var_dump(localeconv()); // decimal_point``

Comment: да, `decimal_point` как запятая стоит.

Comment: А так чтобы сразу и запятая и точка была валидна в `kohana` `validation` это явно не доработано.

Comment: Это было бы не правильно. Если хотите, делайте замену перед сравнением.

Comment: @xEdelweiss: замена как-то несемантично. Надо точно знать, в какой локали текст, который мы валидируем.